# sort php array by index

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I'm having some difficulties sorting a simple array that looks like this:

```
array(4) {
  [32]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [34]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [35]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [33]=>
  string(1) "0"
}
```

I just want to sort it by the index so it would look like this:

```
array(4) {
  [32]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [33]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [34]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [35]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

I tried using `sort($votes);` but this seems to remove the index and my array looks like this afterwards:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "2"
}
```

So what would be the best way of sorting this array so that the index is still the same, but sorted?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You want to use [`ksort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php), which sorts an array by its keys.

> ### ksort
>
> Sorts an array by key, maintaining key to data correlations. This is
>   useful mainly for associative arrays.

Comment: Geez, there's just so many ways to sort so many different types of arrays.  Took forever to find this one, so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For a brief overview of the array sorting functions in PHP, see [**Sorting Arrays**](http://php.net/array.sorting) in the PHP manual.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ksort($votes);`

And the output will be

```
array(4) {
  [32]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [33]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [34]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [35]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

For more info check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php

this looks like you are searching for.

this will sort array and keep existing indexes

```
array(4) {
  [33]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [32]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [35]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [34]=>
  string(1) "2"
}
```