# PHP - Sort Array by index

Tags: php, sorting

I have this array (snippet)

```
array (size=631)
  0 => string '11:27:35.750 INFO - Selenium build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown'
' (length=80)
  1 => string '11:27:35.751 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
' (length=60)
  2 => string '2018-07-17 11:27:35.785:INFO::main: Logging initialized @534ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
' (length=108)
  3 => string '11:27:35.890 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
' (length=80)
  4 => string '11:27:35.891 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver registration is skipped:
' (length=97)
  5 => string 'Unable to create new instances on this machine.
' (length=49)
  6 => string '11:27:35.891 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
' (length=80)
  7 => string '11:27:35.891 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
' (length=90)
  8 => string '11:27:35.893 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver registration is skipped:
' (length=102)
  9 => string ' registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=safari, version=, platform=MAC}] does not match the current platform WIN10
' (length=130)
  10 => string '2018-07-17 11:27:35.966:INFO:osjs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.3.v20170317
```

Is there a built in function which sorts this array by its index, so that the content of index pos 0 is at 10 and vice versa?

Or do I have to write my own?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7925909/sort-php-array-by-index

Comment: Check out the PHP documentation http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are looking for [array_reverse](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php)

```
<?php
$input  = array("php", 4.0, array("green", "red"));
$reversed = array_reverse($input);
$preserved = array_reverse($input, true);

print_r($input);
print_r($reversed);
print_r($preserved);
?>
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => php
    [1] => 4
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => green
            [1] => red
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => green
            [1] => red
        )

    [1] => 4
    [2] => php
)
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => green
            [1] => red
        )

    [1] => 4
    [0] => php
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution. I have to use the function [array_reverse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php)

Comment: Your question was really bad worded, as you asked for sorting by index, not reversing. Maybe edit your question for that.

Comment: It is the same? How is it different.

Comment: No, sorting by index would be something different, you want to reverse the order (your example is sorted/ordered by index already).

Comment: Also: you wanted to have index 0 at position 10, but your example array has a size of 631. So moving 0 to 10 cannot be done by reversing and no logic for sorting that way is visible. If array_reverse is the solution, please edit the question to clarify this, so this can be useful for anyone searching stackoverflow for a similar question.

Comment: "your example array has a size of 631"
Do you think that I will post the whole array here? Of course this is only a snippet as I already mentioned and moving 10 to 0 was just an example.

Comment: I don't really get your problem, I just suggested, that you edit your question, as it is not very clear right now (sorting is not the same as reversing).

Comment: I think everyone but you understands it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176262/discussion-between-franks-and-black).